# Assign a value to input field

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let slider = document.getElementById("slider");
let rightBtn = document.getElementById("rightbutton");
let leftBtn = document.getElementById("leftbutton");

let element = document.getElementById("elementtype").innerHTML;
let celciusBoiling = document.getElementById("celciusboiling").value;


let chlorine = ["Chlorine", 100, 200];

function moveSliderRight() {
    if (rightBtn.onclick) {
        slider.value++;
    }
}


function moveSliderLeft() {
    if (leftBtn.onclick) {
        slider.value--;
    }
}


function main() {
    moveSliderRight();
    moveSliderLeft();

    if (slider.value == parseInt(2)) {
        element = chlorine[0];
        celciusBoiling = chlorine[1];
    }
}
main();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: peachpuff;
}

header {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 10px auto 0px;
}

header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}

.navbar {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 50px auto 50px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.navlinks {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

#nav3 {
    border: none;
}

#intro {
    margin: 0px auto 50px;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
}

#slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 90%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#valuetag {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:25px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#display {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#display div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    text-align: center;
}

span {
    font-size: 15px;
}

.boiling {
    margin-left: 6%;
}

.boilingpointslider {
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
    width: 75px;
}
```

```html
 <header>
        <h1>Periodic Table Gases - Interative Slider</h1>
        <nav>
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navlinks">Boiling Point</div>
                <div class="navlinks" id="nav3">Melting Point</div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
<div id="intro">
<p>Interact with the slider buttons to view the displayed properties held by gases, within the periodic table of elements.</p>
</div>
<h2 id="elementtype">Hydrogen</h2>
<div id="display">
    <div class="boiling">
<h2>Boiling Point</h2>
<input id="celciusboiling" type="number" value="0"><span>&#8451;</span>
<input id="fahrenboiling" type="number"><span>&#8457;</span>
<input id="kelvinboiling" type="number"><span>&#8490;</span>
</div>
<div class="melting">
    <h2>Melting Point</h2>
<input id="celciusmelting" type="number"><span>&#8451;</span>
<input id="fahrenmelting" type="number"><span>&#8457;</span>
<input id="kelvinmelting" type="number"><span>&#8490;</span>
</div>
</div>

<input type="range" min="0" max="9" value="0" id="slider">

<div class="boilingpointslider">  
    <button id="leftbutton" onclick="moveSliderLeft()">Left</button>
    <button id="rightbutton" onclick="moveSliderRight()">Right</button>
</div>
```

I am having issues transferring a value to an input field.

Within the snippet linked their is a heading with the value hydrogen and to the bottom left their is a boiling point heading with a input field for celcius.

I'm trying to achieve a scenario whereby you move the slider along using the buttons and at each value the heading changes to a different element and the input value for just the celcius boiling point changes.

I can't get this to work though. The buttons are working to make the slider move left and right, but for whatever reason i cant get the value to appear within the input field or change the heading. I've displayed the code i have already to get the buttons to move the slider and a snippet of what i thought would allow the changes i want to take place when the slider value changes to 2. I cant get it to to work though

Thanks.

Comment: can you edit the post & replicate the code here on the code snippet.

Comment: Look a lot of info to take in yikes, but snippet attached.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your HTML, but I presume that slider is an input (text or hidden).

The value attribute is a string, even if you assign it a number, so you need to first convert it to a integer if you want to increment or decrement it, like so:

```
slider.value = parseInt(slider.value)++ // or --
```

Note that also you are trying to `parseInt(2)` down in your `main()`, which makes no sense as 2 is already an integer.

Comment: I'm alright with getting the slider to increment, It's just getting the value in the input field to appear when the slider reaches a value. Thanks for the help, sorry yes, the the slider is an input as well. Thanks.